# Windows 8 - Disable Charms Bar

Tags: windows, windows-8, tablet, touchscreen, lockdown

I'm currently working to disable and lockdown tablets, and am having a hell of a time getting this part disabled. On a touch screen tablet, running windows 8, swiping from the right side of the screen will bring up a charms bar. I want this disabled.

I know this is controlled by a registry value (or multiple values) somewhere, but can't locate them. And I've researched this for hours and hours.

Just a heads up, this has nothing to do with CharmBarHints or the Metro Switcher. This also has nothing to do with my mouse's hardware options. Please, don't give me a fix for a PC running windows 8 that is using a touchpad, it's not the same.

I'm just trying to disable the charms bar for a tablet. Also, I know that windows 8.1 will contain a Kiosk Mode, however that will not be officially released until Oct 17th, and I will be shipping this fix out before then.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Were you abel to find a solution for this? The answer below looks like most of the others I've seen that don't do the job.

Comment: For Windows 8, I was not able to. What we ended up doing was restricting so much of the access, that even if the end user brought the charm bar up, they couldn't do much with it.                                                                        My suggestion to you on this, if at all feasible, would be to use the free upgrade MS is providing from 8 to 8.1, and running a user in kiosk mode. Thats about the only way to disable it.

Comment: Thanks, running 8.1 already, but the app I'd like to run in assigned access isn't from the windows store, its custom built, so can't be selected.

Comment: Hey Baelix, why did you delete your XSS question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37974250 ?

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely try going to 
1. "COntrol Panel"-> "Mouse" -> "Device Settings" tab-> "Settings" options -> 
Uncheck the "Enable Edge Swipes" option

Answer (score 0):

Windows charms bar is operated by explorer.exe. So if your app can run without it then you can hack around it by first disabling the autorestart of explorer.exe via (run as administrator):

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "AutoRestartShell" /t REG_DWORD /d 0
```

Then the lines below represent my `launch.bat` - which works in the end as expected:

```
;; kill explorer (this disables all windows functionalities
taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

;; start your kiosk app - should block the batch execution (so explorer.exe doesn't get executed at the end)
"\path\to\your\app.exe"

;; after you close both the app window and the opened chrome window relaunch explorer.exe to give back the functionality to windows
explorer.exe
```

I use the approach outlined above to let a keyboardless kiosk app run. Because with a keyboard you can still close the app with <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this method?

Navigate to the following registry key in Registry Editor:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER>Software>Microsoft>Windows>CurrentVersion>ImmersiveShell
```

Now go to

```
ImmersiveShell > New > Key from the context menu, and then name the new Key as EdgeUI.
```

Right-click the EdgeUI key, point to New, DWORD (32-bit) Value and then name the new DWORD as DisableCharmsHint.

Now double-click the newly created DWORD value, type 1 and click OK. You may also need to reboot Windows for the changes to come into effect.

Once done, it will disable both the top-right and bottom-right hot corners that reveal the Charms Bar.

Source: http://www.techattend.com/disable-charms-bar-in-windows-8-1/